# Voice Recognition - Speech-to-Text - for BlackBerry OS 7

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is there an API to do Speech-to-Text in BlackBerry OS 7?

Comment: I JUST WANT API TO RECOGNIZE  and i will take text and search in my server

Comment: What have you done to try to answer your own question? This question does not demonstrate any attempt at independent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link will help you - 
[iSpeechBlackBerryDemo](http://www.ispeech.org/instructions/sampleprojects/blackberry/instructions.html)

Download the demo code. After register,You received two iSpeech API keys to start speech-enabling your apps. Web Evaluation key and Mobile Production key. Use Mobile Production key to test the demo app.

[iSpeech-Usage-Guidelines](http://www.ispeech.org/downloads/iSpeech-Brand-Usage-Guidelines-2012-04-12.zip)